# Google Cloud Storage generate upload/download URL fails with unicode characters in blobname

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python, google-cloud-storage

I have been testing uploading & downloading on GCS lately, I was able to generate upload & download URLs without problems as long as the blobname or *"path"* was all English letters including spaces and special characters.
However once I use unicode characters in the file name (blobname) it fails with **KeyError**

The [docs](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/storage/latest/google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob) mentions that unicode is supported:

> The name of the blob. This corresponds to the unique path of the
> object in the bucket. If bytes, will be converted to a unicode object.
> Blob / object names can contain any sequence of valid unicode
> characters, of length 1-1024 bytes when UTF-8 encoded.

Code is a few lines:

```
generate_download_signed_url_v4("storage_files", "202209/جراج.png")

def generate_download_signed_url_v4(bucket_name, blob_name):
    storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json('s_account.json')
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(blob_name)
    
    url = blob.generate_signed_url(
        expiration=datetime.timedelta(minutes=10), # This URL is valid for 10 minutes
        method="GET", # Allow GET requests using this URL.
    )
    
    print "Generated GET signed URL:", url
    return url
```

Error is referring to a keyerror along with the unicode value of the first character in the unicode file name portion (blobname)

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/k/Documents/app30/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/Users/k/Documents/app30/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/Users/k/Documents/app30/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/Users/k/Documents/app30/gae/users_app/helpers.py", line 68, in dispatch
    webapp2.RequestHandler.dispatch(self) # dispatch the main handler
  File "/Users/k/Documents/app30/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/Users/k/Documents/app30/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/k/Documents/app30/gae/users_app/helpers.py", line 431, in check_admin
    return myfunction(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/k/Documents/app30/gae/users_app/main.py", line 10796, in get
    my_file_link = self.generate_download_signed_url_v4(root_bucket_name, "572680296//202209/جراج.png")
  File "/Users/k/Documents/app30/gae/users_app/main.py", line 10863, in generate_download_signed_url_v4
    method="GET", # Allow GET requests using this URL.
  File "/Users/k/Documents/app30/gae/users_app/lib/google/cloud/storage/blob.py", line 338, in generate_signed_url
    quoted_name=quote(self.name))
  File "/Users/k/Documents/app30/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/dist27/urllib.py", line 1294, in quote
    return ''.join(map(quoter, s))
KeyError: u'\u062c'
*******> Exception: u'\u062c'
```

Worth mentioning that this is on the local dev server v.340

Comment: You are using Python 2 which has not been supported for several years. Upgrade your code to Python 3.

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley you are right we're on Python 2.7, it's a legacy system still using Python 2.7. Would have been great if moving to Python 3 was easy & quick. But at this point we are still on Python 2.7 and need to work out those challenges until we move to v.3

Comment: In Python 2 **"202209/جراج.png"** is not a valid string. You need to specify Unicode **u"202209/جراج.png"** However, I do not remember how much Python 2 Unicode support the SDK has.

Comment: Note: the documentation that you reference for Unicode support is for Python 3 and not Python 2. Unicode support is native to Python 3 but you must deliberately write code to support Unicode in Python 2.

Comment: If this is on the SDK level then this is more of a problem than I thought, the actual path is actually unicode. the blob_name var "202209/جراج.png" is code generated (not showing in my code above) but I have logged its type before passing to the "generate_download_signed_url_v4" function and I am getting unicide as the type:

>  INFO     2022-09-11 10:20:35,637 helpers.py:2311] 202209/جراج.png
>  INFO     2022-09-11 10:20:35,637 helpers.py:2312] TYPE: <type 'unicode'>

Answer (score 0):

This [issue](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/pull/5625) was fixed in 2018. Looking at the line number and code in

```
 File "/Users/k/Documents/app30/gae/users_app/lib/google/cloud/storage/blob.py", line 338, in generate_signed_url
    quoted_name=quote(self.name))
```

confirms are using a version from before that fix (they match [this](https://github.com/googleapis/python-storage/blame/8b3031610d695927b8e2cfc0e8d142be43fd126f/google/cloud/storage/blob.py#L338) which was changed by [this commit](https://github.com/googleapis/python-storage/commit/3f84aec9fadbdd88161db69e48d910f69c0ddfda)). Upgrade to a version of the library [later than 1.11.0](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/storage/latest/changelog#1110).

Comment: Thanks @David! This seems promising, I am using gcloud components version 340.0.0 due to [this issue](https://groups.google.com/g/google-appengine/c/xhaHazAL6uU), I tried using gcloud components list, but I don't see google-cloud-storage version that I am using. Can you help me find the version I am using and on how to upgrade to a higher version for google-cloud-storage compnent only (as I am still stuck with SDK 340.0.0 at the moment). As noted earlier we are still using Python 2.7 on that system, thanks a million!

Comment: google-cloud-storage is a standard python package on pypi, it's not managed by gcloud. The basic command to upgrade it is `pip install google-cloud-storage --upgrade` but it may be a bit different depending on how your environment is set up - you may need to edit a requirements.txt, enter a virtualenv or something like that.

Comment: thank you, sorry for the late response. I use virtualenv yes, I don't feel safe using `pip install google-cloud-storage --upgrade` to avoid jumping to a python3 version of the package. I found this package though [GoogleAppEngineCloudStorageClient](https://pypi.org/project/GoogleAppEngineCloudStorageClient/) seems to be latest release for GCS on python 2.7. Installed it but no changes.

Comment: On another note, I noticed that including the `version: v4` when generating signed upload URL causes an error `unexpected keyword argument 'version'`. Which seems to indicate that I am using an old version of the package :/